# How to get VGA color with HDMI cable, on HDTV as external monitor?

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, hdmi, vga

I tried connecting my 1080p HDTV as an external monitor to my laptop, both with VGA and HDMI cables.

VGA was good, except it does not support 1900x1200 resolution.

with HDMI, I can set the resolution to 1900x1200, but the colors are very bad. I don't know how to describe it but lots of saturation and gamma I guess. I tried adjusting it manually, from both the television's menu, and Nvidia control panel, but it does not fix it. I nearly tried all combinations. Nothing looks like the original PC screen.

Moreover, I feel that if VGA can do it (copy the color from the PC), HDMI should be able to do it, but how?

Any ideas how to get VGA color with HDMI cable?

Thanks in advance !

### System Details:

- I don't have any converters, just an HDMI cable from the laptop to
  the tv.
- Laptop: Packard Bell EasyNote TM
- Graphics card : NVIDIA
  GeForce GT 420M
- I tried refresh rates 60Hz, 24Hz, nothing changes.

Comment: Can you give the laptop's model? Are you using any sort of converter (i.e. VGA to HDMI)?

Comment: Is there a reason you are setting the resolution to something higher than the TV can handle?  It will need to downscale which will have a negative impact on the image quality.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard I added my system details. Paul; I thought that 1080p means 1900x1200. Is it wrong ? And I tried as you said, lower resolutions do not change the color setting for me.

Comment: 1080p means 1080 horizontal lines and progressive scan (as opposed to interlaced). As such, it's resolution is equal to 1920×1080 (as it conforms to a 16:9 ratio) [(source)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1080p). Have you tried to update your graphics drivers? Or even checked Nvidia Display for something that helps to enable 1080p mode?

Comment: I think the drivers are up-to-date and the Nvidia Control Panel lets me choose 1080p resolution, so I guess it supports 1080p.